# Migrate javascript V12 in V17

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-17

I'm currently trying to migrate this js code (from Odoo V12) into Odoo V17 :

```
odoo.define('report_py3o.report', function (require) {

var ActionManager = require('web.ActionManager');

ActionManager.include({
    _executeReportAction: function (action, options) {
        // Py3o reports
        if ('report_type' in action && action.report_type === 'py3o' ) {
            return this._triggerDownload(action, options, 'py3o');
        } else {
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },

    _makeReportUrls: function(action) {
        var reportUrls = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        reportUrls.py3o = '/report/py3o/' + action.report_name;
        // We may have to build a query string with `action.data`. It's the place
        // were report's using a wizard to customize the output traditionally put
        // their options.
        if (_.isUndefined(action.data) || _.isNull(action.data) ||
            (_.isObject(action.data) && _.isEmpty(action.data))) {
            if (action.context.active_ids) {
                var activeIDsPath = '/' + action.context.active_ids.join(',');
                reportUrls.py3o += activeIDsPath;;
            }
        } else {
            var serializedOptionsPath = '?options=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(action.data));
            serializedOptionsPath += '&context=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(action.context));
            reportUrls.py3o += serializedOptionsPath;
        }
        return reportUrls;
    }
});

});
```

I try to import my js file who i want to inherit like this :
import { action_service } from "@web/webclient/actions/action_service";

But when i use action_service is already undefined

This is the code of the js file (Odoo addon Web) in V17 who i want to inherit :

```
import {
    Component,
    markup,
    onMounted,
    onWillUnmount,
    onError,
    useChildSubEnv,
    xml,
    reactive,
} from "@odoo/owl";
import { downloadReport, getReportUrl } from "./reports/utils";

class BlankComponent extends Component {
    static props = ["onMounted", "withControlPanel", "*"];
    static template = xml`
        
            
                
            
        `;
    static components = { ControlPanel };

    setup() {
        useChildSubEnv({ config: { breadcrumbs: [], noBreadcrumbs: true } });
        onMounted(() => this.props.onMounted());
    }
}

const actionHandlersRegistry = registry.category("action_handlers");
const actionRegistry = registry.category("actions");
const viewRegistry = registry.category("views");

/** @typedef {number|false} ActionId */
/** @typedef {Object} ActionDescription */
/** @typedef {"current" | "fullscreen" | "new" | "main" | "self" | "inline"} ActionMode */
/** @typedef {string} ActionTag */
/** @typedef {string} ActionXMLId */
/** @typedef {Object} Context */
/** @typedef {Function} CallableFunction */
/** @typedef {string} ViewType */

/** @typedef {ActionId|ActionXMLId|ActionTag|ActionDescription} ActionRequest */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ActionOptions
 * @property {Context} [additionalContext]
 * @property {boolean} [clearBreadcrumbs]
 * @property {CallableFunction} [onClose]
 * @property {Object} [props]
 * @property {ViewType} [viewType]
 */

export async function clearUncommittedChanges(env) {
    const callbacks = [];
    env.bus.trigger("CLEAR-UNCOMMITTED-CHANGES", callbacks);
    const res = await Promise.all(callbacks.map((fn) => fn()));
    return !res.includes(false);
}

export const standardActionServiceProps = {
    action: Object, // prop added by _getActionInfo
    actionId: { type: Number, optional: true }, // prop added by _getActionInfo
    className: String, // prop added by the ActionContainer
    globalState: { type: Object, optional: true }, // prop added by _updateUI
    state: { type: Object, optional: true }, // prop added by _updateUI
};

function parseActiveIds(ids) {
    const activeIds = [];
    if (typeof ids === "string") {
        activeIds.push(...ids.split(",").map(Number));
    } else if (typeof ids === "number") {
        activeIds.push(ids);
    }
    return activeIds;
}

const DIALOG_SIZES = {
    "extra-large": "xl",
    large: "lg",
    medium: "md",
    small: "sm",
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Errors
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

export class ControllerNotFoundError extends Error {}

export class InvalidButtonParamsError extends Error {}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ActionManager (Service)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// regex that matches context keys not to forward from an action to another
const CTX_KEY_REGEX =
    /^(?:(?:default_|search_default_|show_).+|.+_view_ref|group_by|group_by_no_leaf|active_id|active_ids|orderedBy)$/;

// only register this template once for all dynamic classes ControllerComponent
const ControllerComponentTemplate = xml``;

function makeActionManager(env) {
    const keepLast = new KeepLast();
    let id = 0;
    let controllerStack = [];
    let dialogCloseProm;
    let actionCache = {};
    let dialog = null;
    
    /**
     * Executes actions of type 'ir.actions.report'.
     *
     * @private
     * @param {ReportAction} action
     * @param {ActionOptions} options
     */
    async function _executeReportAction(action, options) {
        const handlers = registry.category("ir.actions.report handlers").getAll();
        for (const handler of handlers) {
            const result = await handler(action, options, env);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        if (action.report_type === "qweb-html") {
            return _executeReportClientAction(action, options);
        } else if (action.report_type === "qweb-pdf" || action.report_type === "qweb-text") {
            const type = action.report_type.slice(5);
            let success, message;
            env.services.ui.block();
            try {
                const downloadContext = { ...env.services.user.context };
                if (action.context) {
                    Object.assign(downloadContext, action.context);
                }
                ({ success, message } = await downloadReport(
                    env.services.rpc,
                    action,
                    type,
                    downloadContext
                ));
            } finally {
                env.services.ui.unblock();
            }
            if (message) {
                env.services.notification.add(message, {
                    sticky: true,
                    title: _t("Report"),
                });
            }
            if (!success) {
                return _executeReportClientAction(action, options);
            }
            const { onClose } = options;
            if (action.close_on_report_download) {
                return doAction({ type: "ir.actions.act_window_close" }, { onClose });
            } else if (onClose) {
                onClose();
            }
        } else {
            console.error(
                `The ActionManager can't handle reports of type ${action.report_type}`,
                action
            );
        }
    }
};
```

Do you have any idea how to migrate this code in his version 17 ?

Thank's in advance ;)

Comment: Use `actionService` instead of `action_service`